# Why are most UDP packets from a servlet filter not showing up in Graphite?

Tags: java, networking, udp, packet, datagram

I have the following in a servlet filter:

```java
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {        
    long startTimeNano = System.nanoTime();

    chain.doFilter(request, response);

    long endTimeNano = System.nanoTime();
    long differenceNano = endTimeNano - startTimeNano;
    long differenceMilliseconds = differenceNano / 1000000;

    try {
        reportResponseTimeToGraphite(differenceMilliseconds);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Logger.log(getClass(), "Response time measure failed.");
    }
}
```

`reportResponseTimeToGraphite` simply sends a UDP packet to a Graphite server:

```java
private void reportResponseTimeToGraphite(long differenceMilliseconds) throws IOException {
    int currentUnixTimeSeconds = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L);

    String message = GRAPHITE_LABEL + " " + String.valueOf(differenceMilliseconds) + " " + String.valueOf(currentUnixTimeSeconds);

    DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
    InetAddress recipientIP = InetAddress.getByName(GRAPHITE_SERVER);
    byte[] sendData = message.getBytes();
    DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, recipientIP, GRAPHITE_PORT);

    clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
    clientSocket.close();
}
```

Strangely is this works *only some of the time*. Here's a sample section of the Graph, for a machine dealing with over 1000 requests per minute:

[image: Graph with partial data]

A lot of the time, there are hour(s)-long stretches with no data points shown in the graph.

If it's relevant, the Graphite server is running on EC2.